# mongoose find multiple documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have one basic `User` schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Now I want to implement `dual login` feature,

```
  async.parallel([
    function (cb) {
      User.findOne({$and: [{name: req.body.username1}, {password: req.body.password1}]}, function (err, u) {
        if (!u)
          err = "User1 dose not exist";
        cb(err, u)
      });
    },
    function (cb) {
      User.findOne({$and: [{name: req.body.username2}, {password: req.body.password2}]}, function (err, u) {
        if (!u)
          err = "User2 dose not exist";
        cb(err, u)
      });
    }
  ], function (err, results) {
      ....
```

I want to whether there is simple way to find those two user information in one `User.find()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just use [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/). Also your use of [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) is redundant here:

```js
  User.find({
      "$or": [
         { "name": req.body.username1, "password": req.body.password1 },
         { "name": req.body.username2, "password": req.body.password2 }
      ]
  },function(err,result) {
      // logic in here

  })
```

And then process whatever logic you need to validate the response, with the clearest case being that if the response is not at least two items long then one of the selections was not found.

This is one of those cases where of course "username" should have a unique constraint.